# how can I use nginx deploy static audio file and record its download statistics?

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx to serve static audio files. I also want to record statistics about its download info, like ip, url etc and store these data to db. After handling the get request to the audio file, can Nginx call my api?

If so, how would I do that ?

Comment: This question is answered well on serverfault, see [How to serve html code from nginx and also ping upstream server for same request?](http://serverfault.com/questions/491139/how-to-serve-html-code-from-nginx-and-also-ping-upstream-server-for-same-request/)